# onstart and oncomplete don't work in datatable with p:commandLink

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I wrote a JS function which shows a "Loading" DIV while I'm loading the next screen (I'm using commanlinks and it works perfectly, with onstart="showthemodal" oncomlete="hidethemodal").

Now the problem is in this page in particular I have a datatable (I wrote the code above) which have many commandlinks inside the datatable and the onstart and oncomplete here don't work. I'm not able to show the modal without change the appearance of my buttons. Thanks for your support
Does anyone know how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="user"
            tableStyle="table-layout: auto"
            value="#{gestionUsuariosController.listaUsuarios}" paginator="true"
            rows="10" lazy="true" dynamic="true"
            style="font-size:16px;">

            <p:column styleClass="ellipsis"
                sortBy="#{user.userName}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Nombre" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="userName" value="#{user.userName}" />
                <p:tooltip for="userName" value="#{user.userName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column styleClass="ellipsis"
                sortBy="#{user.userName}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Password" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="password" value="#{user.password}" />
                <p:tooltip for="password" value="#{user.password}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column styleClass="ellipsis" style="width: 80px;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Accion" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandLink action="consulta" onstart="javascript:bloquearInterfaz();" oncomplete="javascript:desbloquearInterfaz();">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/lupa.png"  height="20px"/>
                    <f:param name="userName" value="#{user.userName}" />
                </p:commandLink>
                &nbsp;
                <p:commandLink action="modificacion" onstart="javascript:bloquearInterfaz();" oncomplete="javascript:desbloquearInterfaz();">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icono_edit.png" height="20px" />
                    <f:param name="userName" value="#{user.userName}" />
                </p:commandLink>
                &nbsp;
                <p:commandLink action="baja" onstart="javascript:bloquearInterfaz();" oncomplete="javascript:desbloquearInterfaz();">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/borrar.png"  height="20px" />
                    <f:param name="userName" value="#{user.userName}" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Try removing `javascript:` from `onstart="javascript:bloquearInterfaz();"` and `oncomplete="javascript:desbloquearInterfaz();"`.

Comment: It doesnt work, thank you Anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it clear `onstart` and `oncompelte` is a client side method that mean that you can't connect it to your `managedBean` ( execute a method ) however it's possible to make it work (execute a managedBean method ) with `p:remoteCommand`

it's look like this

***mypage.xhtml***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  myfunction () {
          ...
  }            
</script>

...

<p:commandButton  onstart="myfunction() "  />
```

and if you want to execut a managedBean method

***mypage.xhtml***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   myfunction () {
        ...
        cpr();
   }            
</script>

...

<p:remoteCommand  name="cpr" actionListener="#{managedBean.method()}"  />
<p:commandButton  onstart="myfunction() "  />
```

hope that helped you.

Comment: @JasperdeVries i am ok with you when you talk about managedBean but i think that to make a complete answer it was importante to talk about it even if it's a little bit out of topic

Comment: Thank u very much!!! It works perfectly, now i have to change the appereance of the button but i guess its quite simple!

Comment: @Pilar if it's worked please make it an answer about the appereance  of the button i think you will be satisfy with the Primefaces web site

Comment: @Yagami Light It works but im not able to change the appereance of the buttons to the png pictures i had choose for the buttons :(

Comment: @Pilar what do you mean by appereance did you see this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml

Comment: @YagamiLight Sorry for my english i mean instead os a square button i would like to replace ir fot my own picture

Comment: `<h:commandButton action="#{some_action}" image="pathtotheimage.png" />` this is how you can make it  do not forget to make the right path

Comment: @YagamiLightYes this works! but now back to the begining onstart and oncomplete function only works with p:commandButton inside the datatable :(

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand where is the problem ?!?

Comment: I wrote a JS function wich shows a Loading DIV while im loading the next screen (Im using commanlinks and it works perfectly, with onstart="showthemodal" oncomlete="hidethemodal") . Now the problem is In this page in particular i have a datatable (I wrote the code above) wich have many commandlinks inside the datatable and the onstart and oncomplete here dont work. Im not able to show the modal without change the appereance of my buttons. Thanks for your support

Comment: neither im getting really desesperate haha

Comment: non @Pilar you will get it i am here to help you i can give you an other solution if you want for your  Loading DIV are you interested ?!?

Comment: I have tried blocking the body of my page too. But besides the ajax events sttoped to work inside the datatable blockui neither works for the whole body inside the datatable. What happends inside the datatable. Nothing works fine for me!

Comment: try this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml it's showing a status waiting bar for the user

Comment: Thak u very much i really appreciate your help I'll take a look to it quietly but im using templates i have lot of buttons links and forms in my page. Im a newbie and im not sure how to apply it. Thank u again :)

Comment: @Pilar ask an other question how to apply ajaxStatus and it will be my pleasure to help u implement it

Comment: here I go!!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897415/can-use-ajaxstatus-while-the-next-page-is-loading

Thaks a lot i would like to help you back but i guees it will require a long long time haha

Comment: @YagamiLight  
here I go!!! stackoverflow.com/questions/39897415/… Thaks a lot i would like to help you back but i guees it will require a long long time haha